# Feature-Request: Mini games on sidebar to play for fun

Tags: feature-request

There should be some random mini-games on sidebar which can be played. Games like
 **`pac-man`:**

[image]

**`tetris:`**

[image]

**`bubble shooter:`**

[image]

will look good on the side-bar. It will give a good feeling to the visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I appreciate the suggestion, and yeah, we're a bunch of gamers so theoretically adding something like this to the site would be fun, it's very unlikely to happen. It would be a lot of dev time to add something that doesn't really benefit the network as a whole, and on top of that, Stack Exchange is [working to somewhat consolidate their site theming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) right now in order to create a more cohesive experience across the network (and to make it easier on the devs etc. to push changes to all sites without breaking things, etc).

So, while this is an interesting suggestion, I can pretty much guarantee that this will be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).